# how to search values in a file and replace

Tags: python

I have a list which has values to search for in a file and a dictionary with the values it should be replaced with,i gave a sample content of the file and the same output,am unsure as to how to search and replace?can anyone provide guidance?

```
   list_to_search =['TRC_BTM', 'TRC_HCI', 'TRC_L2CAP']
    dict = {'TRC_BTM': '6', 'TRC_HCI': '6', 'TRC_L2CAP': '6'}

    filename ='file.conf'
f = open(filename, 'r')
for value in list_to_search :
    print "dummy"
    #1.search value in file 
    #2.replace with dict[value]
f.close()

INPUT:-
    #comment1  
    TRC_BTAPP only.
    TRC_BTM=2
    TRC_HCI=2
    TRC_L2CAP=2
    #comment2

OUTPUT:-
    #comment1  
    TRC_BTAPP only.
    TRC_BTM=6
    TRC_HCI=6
    TRC_L2CAP=6
    #comment2
    ...
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all? For starters, look into this : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Comment: does your input only contains string of shown type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got for you another solution, basically what it does, instead of reading whole content of file into memory, you read line by line and check in each line you read if it has one of `elements of list_to_search`, then modify it if so:

```
list_to_search =['TRC_BTM', 'TRC_HCI', 'TRC_L2CAP']
myDict = {'TRC_BTM': '6', 'TRC_HCI': '6', 'TRC_L2CAP': '6'}

filename ='file.conf'

with open(filename, 'rb+') as f:

    while True:         
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break          
        for key in list_to_search:
            if key in line:
                f.seek(-len(line),1)
                f.write(key + '=' + myDict[key] + '\n')
                f.flush()
```

EDIT: In response to your comment below:

```
with open(filename, 'rb+') as f:

    while True:         
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break        
        if '=2' in line:
                f.seek(-len(line),1)
                f.write(line.split('=2')[0]+'=6')
                f.flush()
```

Comment: Can we change the implementation to search for "=2" in the file and then replace all occurences wiht "=6"

Comment: Yes, for sure you can do that, but this will lead to different output then what you asked for, be aware of that!

Answer (score 1):

If and only if the `file contains the strings as your sample input` the following method will work:

Instead of printing, you could write the output into a file if you wish:

**My code:**

```
list_to_search =['TRC_BTM', 'TRC_HCI', 'TRC_L2CAP']
dict = {'TRC_BTM': '6', 'TRC_HCI': '6', 'TRC_L2CAP': '6'}

filename ='test.txt'    

for a in open(filename):
    if any(ext in a for ext in list_to_search):
        for value in list_to_search:
            if value in a and "=" in a:
                print value+"="+dict[value]
    else:
        print a
```

**Modified Code:**

```
list_to_search =['TRC_BTM', 'TRC_HCI', 'TRC_L2CAP']
dict = {'TRC_BTM': '6', 'TRC_HCI': '6', 'TRC_L2CAP': '6'}

filename ='test.txt'

output_writer=[]
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for a in f:
        print a
        if any(ext in a for ext in list_to_search):
            for value in list_to_search:
                if value in a and "=" in a:
                    output_writer.append(value+"="+dict[value])
                    #print value+"="+dict[value]
        else:
            # print a
            output_writer.append(a.strip())

output="\n".join(output_writer)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Comment: basically i need to update the file with the new repaced values aswell?not just print

Comment: I see it adds a new line for everyline it didnt change...do you see the same too?,can we not join using a new line `output="\n".join(output_writer)` ,only change should be the value change,thats it

Comment: we are opening a different file and writing to a different file,need to write to ths same file?